# Read and concat multiple excel files based on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

```
path = '/Desktop/somefolder'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(path+filename) as f:
         - read the 3-4 excel files and attach the path
         - be able to concat them based on a specific column
```

filename gives me the name of the file I have in the directory. My idea was to concat the filename with the path to be able to read and concat them.

I am not sure how to use the filename that I get to be able to load it as a df and concat it.

Comment: Have you considered using `pd.read_excel` yet?

Comment: Yes, that isn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405182/combine-multiple-workbooks-into-a-single-xlsx-workbook-using-python

Comment: No, the link does not resolve this issue. @Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = '/Desktop/somefolder/'

dfs = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel(path+filename, engine='openpyxl'))

pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

Comment: I am getting an error : --> Unknown engine: <module 'openpyxl' from '/opt/anaconda3/envs/union_rates_time_series/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py'> @user16367225

Comment: Try installing `conda install -c anaconda openpyxl` in Anaconda Prompt in your environment. Make sure you install in it in the right environment.

Answer (score 1):

Read the data into data frames

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')
```

Create filtered data frames

```
df1Filtered = df1[df1["YourColumnName"].("YourColumnValues")
df2Filtered = df2[df2["YourColumnName"].("YourColumnValues")
```

Concat the filtered data frames

```
NewDF = pd.concat([df1Filtered, df2Filtered])
```

Write a new file to excel

```
NewDF.to_excel('NewFile.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but this starts to get ugly if you have 15 to 16 excel files...

Comment: You're welcome, and that is subjective, original post said 3-4 excel files so your mileage may vary.