# import csv to xlsx python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm trying to put some data from a csv file to exist excel file.
my exist excel file contains images and xlrd cannot get images.
I try to use xlsxwriter but it cannot append to existing xslx.
the only solution I've found is to use openpyxl.

```
import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('my_exist_file')
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
with open("my_csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
           -here is my problem-
```

how can I write the csv data (that is a table) to a specific location in the exist xslx? I want that my table will start at K2 cell.

thanks!

Comment: pandas has an excellent `read_csv` method, and you can add data to the excelfile with [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221655/1562285) (I would still keep some backups of the excel before you try, since it might erase the other content on the sheet)

Comment: thanks, I took a look in the workaround and I insert my csv data to: data=pandas.read_csv("my_csv"), after that I tried to data.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1") but my data isn't in utf-8. how can I decode it? + I didn't understand where I put K2 cell to be the starting cell of my csv in the exist file

Comment: Do you remember how was your solution? I have a similar issue here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966833/populate-an-excel-file-from-csv-input-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## reading the CSV

using [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to extract the information

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(my_filename)
```

Options you might need to specify

- sep: which separator is used
- encoding
- header: Is the first row a row of labels?
- index_col: is the first column an index

## adding to an excel worksheet

inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221655/1562285
check the [`pandas.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) documentation for other possible options

```
book = load_workbook(old_filename)
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
with pd.ExcelWriter(new_filename, engine='openpyxl')  as writer:

    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, startcol=10, engine='openpyxl')
```

The startrow and startcol say where in the worksheet you want to paste your data.

This method might overwrite the previous content on this worksheet. If it does, you will have to loop over the columns and rows of the DataFrame and add them semi-manually to the worksheet

## Inserting images

If you have the images to insert somewhere externally you can use the code from the [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#inserting-an-image)

```
    from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
    ws = book['sheet_name_for_images']
    ws['A1'] = 'You should see three logos below'
    img = Image('logo.png')

    # add to worksheet and anchor next to cells
    ws.add_image(img, 'A1')
```

I did not test this, and you might need to insert this code before the `writer.sheets = ...`

Comment: the problem now is that my exist xlsx file contains images and in the new file they aren't there :(

Comment: from the Openpyxl documentation: `openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name.`

Comment: can I insert the images when I build the new file?

Comment: I dd not test this, but I added a first attempt in the code

Answer (score 0):

Use the worksheet's cell method to update a specific cell

```
sheet.cell(row=<row>, column=<col>, value=<val>)
```

It is usually a good idea to use `keep_vba=True` while loading workbook. Check [the help page](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#playing-with-data) for more details.

Also check [answer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381384/modify-an-existing-excel-file-using-openpyxl-in-python) this question.

Comment: thanks, I tried this but now in cell K2 I have only one letter and not all my table..