# Why doesn't openpyxl recognize the name of a sheet in an existing excel file that I open?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using the following code to open an existing Excel file in python 3.6, Excel 2016:

```
Shnm = my_pyx.get_sheet_names() 
sheet = my_pyx.get_sheet_by_name(Shnm[0])

from openpyxl import load_workbook
# Class to manage excel data with openpyxl.

class Copy_excel:
    def __init__(self,src):
        self.wb = load_workbook(src)
        self.ws = self.wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
        self.dest="destination.xlsx"

    # Write the value in the cell defined by row_dest+column_dest         
    def write_workbook(self,row_dest,column_dest,value):
        c = self.ws.cell(row = row_dest, column = column_dest)
        c.value = value

    # Save excel file
    def save_excel(self) :  
        self.wb.save(self.dest)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752861/7442782)

So when I do:

```
row_dest=2
column_dest=6   
workbook = Copy_excel(my_file)
data=60
workbook.write_workbook(2,6,data )
workbook.save_excel()
```

where: 
my_file is a str like `filename.xlsx` and sheet is a str with the sheet name.

It bugs me with an error stating that the sheet name mentioned does not exist.

I also tried to replace:

`self.ws = self.wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)`

with

```
self.ws = self.wb[sheet]
```

but I still receive the same error.

Comment: It seems that the variable `sheet` in `self.ws = self.wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)` is not passed into the init function of your class. Have you ruled that out? Also, you can list all the sheets in your workbook with `self.wb.sheetnames`. Can you add an `assert sheet in self.wb.sheetnames` to make sure the sheet actually exists?

Comment: physically checking the Excel file, I see it exists ! but I did not get what I exactly should do, since I am new to using classes, how do I check this in the command prompt ?

Comment: should I insert assert sheet in self.wb.sheetnames in a line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was setting:

```
sheet = my_pyx.get_sheet_by_name(Shnm[0])
```

And later set:

```
self.ws = self.wb[sheet]
```

Since sheet is not the sheet name but the actual sheet object you should use:

```
self.ws = self.wb[Shnm[0]]
```

I have tried this code and it worked for me:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# Class to manage excel data with openpyxl.

class Copy_excel:
    def __init__(self,src):
        self.wb = load_workbook(src)
        Shnm = self.wb.sheetnames
        self.ws = self.wb[Shnm[0]]
        self.ws = self.wb[sheet]
        self.dest='path\\to\\Copy.xlsx'

    # Write the value in the cell defined by row_dest+column_dest
    def write_workbook(self,row_dest,column_dest,value):
        c = self.ws.cell(row = row_dest, column = column_dest)
        c.value = value

    # Save excel file
    def save_excel(self) :
        self.wb.save(self.dest)

row_dest=2
column_dest=6
workbook = Copy_excel('path\\to\\file.xlsx')
data=60
workbook.write_workbook(2,6,data )
workbook.save_excel()
```

Comment: actually it was only my error in the question !! and no it does not work for me the same

Comment: Where do you set the sheet variable? It's not visible in your Example.

Comment: Shnm = my_pyx.get_sheet_names() 
sheet = my_pyx.get_sheet_by_name(Shnm[0])

Comment: I added it to the question text as well

Comment: is a crazy vandal just throwing negative votes at questions and answers ?

Comment: seems like that. Ok could you try using `self.ws = self.wb[Shnm[0]]` like I did in my Answer post.

Comment: also you could check if the value of `Shnm[0]` is in `self.wb.sheetnames`

Comment: This worked !! I was using : sheet = my_pyx.get_sheet_by_name(Shnm[0]) and it was not a sheet name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189210/discussion-between-fabiospaghetti-and-hawk59).

Comment: I guess I should ask a new question, cause I need to variate the number over a range