# Python: output variables onto existing excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I was wondering how to output using Python variables onto an existing excel sheet.

Given the excel column

```
[A] [B] [C] [D] [E] [F] [G] [H] [I] [J]
```

Note:

- List item  [A] [B] [C] [D] : are given in one excel file (text.xlsx)
- I have strings on [E] [F] , [H] [I] (manipulations based on [A][B][C][D]) ready as a variable
- I have an int (%) on [G] [J] (manipulations based on [A][B][C][D]) ready as a variable

For excel input, I am using `xlrd`, but I was wondering **how do I output these variables onto the same/existing excel file**? Which library do I use?

Answer (score 4):

There are python packages available to work with Excel files that will run on any Python platform and that do not require either Windows or Excel to be used. They are fast, reliable and open source like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/).

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381384/modify-an-existing-excel-file-using-openpyxl-in-python) may help to you to update existing excel file.