# How to use python to create and change excel templates?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My day to day job involves updating excel templates every month then review the monthly changes. The updates are from a standardized file and go into the specific cells in respective excel files. The cells are not necessarily the same location (i.e. same cell in every file), but they are in the same line with the current month.

There is also a sheet that have to be updated. It's from the same sheet of a standard download, but only a different month (the current month).

There are hundreds of templates to update each month. I wonder if python can change the updates all at once.

I just started learning python with excel and I think it should be able to do it. Not sure if pandas is the right path?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. that said, you'll probably see a good solution from generating a new file, consuming the old one as an input along with the other files

Comment: Here's an example of how to use openpyxl to write to cells in an excel worksheet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382230/530160

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Nick! for example, if I have a hundred files for Feb., I need to update all of them to March by adding two tabs in each file (by copying the two Feb. tabs and change names to March), adding March values (from the same file) to the March tabs (values will be in the same line with March date, not necessarily the same cell in each file) and copying and pasting the March assumptions tab from each report to the tab in respective file. The procedure to update each file is the same, it's just the values might be in different cells in each file.

Comment: Can I update those files with openpyxl?